# Excel how to move word in one cell from right to left?

Tags: excel

I have far to many cells that I need to change to do it manually , here's an example

***John Johnson-22***

Need turned into:

***22-John Johnson***

Is there a way to do it quick and easy ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With data in **A1**, in **B1** enter:

```
=MID(A1,FIND("-",A1,1)+1,9999) & "-" & LEFT(A1,FIND("-",A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Is that going to change every column ? I mean is it going to do it for B1,B2,B3 etc ?

Comment: @VladimirČeperković  If you have data in column **A**, then copy the formula in **B1** downwards.